# Book to walk you through java APIs?

Tags: java

I saw this post :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441198/has-anyone-learned-how-to-program-in-21-days/441224#441224

and I'm not familiar with java APIs, which books do you think will really help me get familiar with those APIs?

Answer (score 5):

[Java in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596002831), David Flanagan

Comment: +1 This one helped after learning basic language skills

Comment: +1 also. Clean, concise example of all major language constructs and standard classes. Details lists of all standard classes and methods with *some* description of usage, but not a lot for the "uncommon" structures.  The "Java Platform" section, about 100 pages in the 5th ed., is pure gold.

Answer (score 3):

Java has lots of APIs!  Which ones are you interested in becoming familiar with?

What's nice, though, is that Javadocs tend to make APIs easy to learn, by providing method signatures and short descriptions.

Many APIs also have more in-depth tutorials online that you can read.  In many cases this can be easier / more accessible / cheaper than buying books.

I would start off with Java Collections, as they are used in most Java applications:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html

Note that this is one of Sun's "Trail" tutorials, which are very helpful.  Check out the others as well, for those libraries that you are interested in learning.  Here is the main index:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058) by Josh Bloch

Comment: Effective Java is largely not about any particular APIs, though it can be great for learning how to correctly design your own.

Comment: Actually, this will help you learn to use Java Effectively, after you are familiar with it.  It will tell you very little about the APIs.  (But it is a great book.)

Comment: I agree, while it doesn't cover too many apis exensively, it does cover the core libraries ( java.lang for instance )

Answer (score 0):

You should really start at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html

These tutorials are well written, and will get you up to speed quickly.  For all the details, go to the documentation at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/

If you insist on a book, Thinking in Java by Eckel is not bad, though Eckel can be a bit longwinded and obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Cookbook](http://javacook.darwinsys.com/) contains examples to many API's
Then javadoc can be used to adapt to own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[Java 7- complete reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071606300) This books not out yet but it might help a lot along with the java docs and all the additional material the others have mentioned.